# Show that $\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots + (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n - 2} + (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that
$$
\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots + (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n - 2} + (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^2}
$$
For all $x \in R$ and for all $n \in N$.

I have to do this proof using integrals. I know that the integral of the left side is
$$
\int \frac{1}{1 + x^2} dx = \text{arctan } x + C
$$
My idea is now to take the integral of each part of the right side, sum them and show that the integral of the first part $1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots$ is equal to $\text{arctan } x$ and that the integral of the last part $(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n - 2} + (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^2}$ is the ramainder $C$. But i am uncertain about how to show that these parts are the same after i find the integrals.

Comment: @MartinR The series is defintley correct. I know that for a fact

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $2x$ before integrating lets you use the series for $\ln x$ instead of $\arctan x$. The constant of integration can be handled by picking an initial point for the integration. I'd recommend $0$ (that is, apply $\int_0^{x'}dx$ to both sides).

Comment: I have a pretty straightforward answer using complex numbers. Interested?

Comment: The most straightforward proof is to see that multiplying both sides by $1+x^2$ yields to the same result...

Comment: This is a geometric sum. You can prove it without doing any integrals.